# Data mínima no Ionic Native DatePicker

Tags: ionic, typescript

Estou utilizando o plugin DatePicker para receber uma data, consigo pegar a data normalmente, o problema ocorre quando uso a propriedade minDate, no meu entendimento, isso seria uma data minima para seleção, mas quando seto uma data na propriedade, nada acontece, há algum formato especifico de data para Android?

```
getDateFinal() {
    this.datePicker.show({
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date',
      minDate: new Date(),
      androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_DARK
    }).then(
      date => this.dataFinal = this.sharedProvider.transformDate(date),
      err => console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)
    );
  }
```

Documentação: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/date-picker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme a documentação em https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker#mindate---ios-android-windows :

> minDate is a Date object for iOS and a millisecond precision unix
>   timestamp for Android, so you need to account for that when using the
>   plugin. Also, on Android, only the date is enforced (time is not).

Ou seja, para funcionar em Android é preciso passar a data em UNIX timestamp ao invés de um objeto date.

`minDate: new Date().getTime() / 1000`

Comment: Então cara, consegui resolver aqui, realmente precisa chamar o método getTime() no Android.